# Automate iSeries SFTP to a remote SFTP host

Tags: ssh, ibm-midrange

I would like to set up SFTP for our internal iSeries servers. I have 4 iSeries servers and would like to SFTP between them all.  Does anyone have a good resource for helping me to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Downvoted because the question is way too vague.  Please include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example showing what code you were trying along with a specific problem description.

Comment: This is entirely possible - see https://www.scottklement.com/presentations/Setting%20up%20and%20Scripting%20the%20OpenSSH,%20SFTP%20and%20SCP%20Utilities%20on%20IBM%20i.pdf (for example).

Comment: Upvote but someone should put an example qsh  cmd(&mycmd)

Comment: "SFTP between them all" meaning that every one of your 4 machines should act both as an SFTP client and SFTP server? That kind-of defeats the purpose of the SFTP protocol itself. Maybe you could consider deploying an SFTP server that all 4 of your machines will share (all 4 being clients to that one SFTP server)